# Bootstrap Triangle Glyphicon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I am trying to add the Triangle Glyph to my website from Bootstrap. Problem is I had a outdated version of Bootstrap, I had **3.3.2**. I guess I needed **3.3.3** for the Glyphicon I would like. I tried downloading the new font files, and I believe I succeeded in that. Yet when I try to add in the Glyphicon it does not seem to work.

So my question is what do I have to do in addition to add the new Glyphicons? I can not completely re-insert the bootstrap.css because I have made changes to it.

**UPDATE**
I have also added this code to my bootstrap.css:

```
.glyphicon-triangle-bottom:before {
  content: "\e252";
}
.glyphicon-triangle-top:before {
  content: "\e253";
}
```

Yet the Glyphicon will not pop up.

Comment: It seems like v3.3.2 already has [triangle glyphicon](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.2/less/glyphicons.less#L291)

Comment: Verify you are referencing your updated bootstrap files, you have cleared the cache in your browser, and can view the other glyphicons, not just the triangles.

Comment: It was a problem with the Cache I believe! :) Thank You

Comment: Great! Anyway, you don't need any modified files... [v3.3.2 did include triangles](https://jsfiddle.net/aje9wbbh/) :D

Comment: "there are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors"

Answer (score 2):

For Bootstrap 3.3.2, you can use 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up' and 'glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down' as a close replacement.